# Where to put network requests when app first starts

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

When app starts I need to do some network requests. For example, App fetches my servers public key to operate a secure restful connection. If it can get the key, It does other network operations. My problem is that these operations are nested so one is finished, other one start but If there is a problem  with one of them I need to display a message. I have AppDelegate class and SplashViewController in which I can do these operations. I'm not sure what will be the best approach in terms of speed when doing that;

1-) Start operations in AppDelegate and with notification, notify splashviewcontroller and display message If there is an error.

2-)Start operations in SplashViewController class.

3-)Wait all network operations to be finished before opening SplashViewController (I'm not sure If I can display error message in AppDelegate class)

Example code I run at AppDelegate;

```
 APIClient.checkCMS { (result) in
  switch result{
    case .error(let error):
        print(error)
        //Notify SplashViewController?
    case .success(let returnedObject):
        print(returnedObject)
        print("Devam")
               }
  }
```

Comment: I would go with number 1. (assuming your network code will be in some service and not in app delegate.)

Comment: I would also recommend looking into an asynchronous wrapper such as PromiseKit; it will make this a lot tidier.

Comment: I know PromiseKit but It is nothing to do with my problem. I mean my problem is I can't decide where to put promisekit or some network codes.. Appdelegate or splash class?

Comment: @EmreO. It depends on your requirements. Would you let the user wait on the SplashScreen while your data is downloading / block the UI? Or would you do an async request and proceed to the app in a blank state (or cached state).

Comment: @Hapeki I'll wait in every-situation but I want to minimize that wait time.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you are even thinking about using notifications here to communicate between view controllers is probably a code smell. I think the `AppDelegate` approach is definitely wrong.

I'm making some assumptions about your app that may be incorrect, namely that you are using a storyboard/xibs and that your SplashVC is going to be instantiated and presented when the app runs, regardless of the state of the network call (i.e. the app isn't just going to hang until the outcome of the network call is known).

In this scenario, if you make the call from the `AppDelegate` you will use `NSNotificationCenter` to update the SplashVC. This seems like a bad idea, just because it introduces unnecessary complication to the design. You might *just conceivably* do everything from the `AppDelegate` if you are loading the VCs manually in code, but even then you probably don't really want the app to show nothing until the network call completes.

The way I would handle this is as follows:

1. (If you haven't already done it) encapsulate all of your network requests into a service object of some kind. Then you can use Dependency Injection with a singleton scope (perhaps using Swinject or another similar library). This would allow you to make network requests from anywhere in the app they are required.
2. Have a default VC (maybe SplashVC, or some other root VC) that loads first and dependency injects the network service from 1
3. Make the calls in the `viewDidLoad` of the SplashVC. Handle errors appropriately, (by showing an alert, or by presenting a custom modal VC, or whatever you like. This avoids having the app just show a black screen if the request is slow).

Comment: I have APIClient class which handles network requests. Actually I think we are in same side but I couldn't clearly tell my point. For example,  time till SplashVC is opening is 3 second. If I start all requests in SplashVC, I waited more 3 second but If I start them at AppDelegate, It means I gain 3 less second. If we come why I want to use notification is that If some requests fails, I need to display error message.

Comment: Why use a singleton to perform network requests when these can be static methods? E.g. ApiHandler.login(.....)

Comment: @Hapeki. In a word, testing. It's a dependency injected object with singleton scope, not an actual singleton - so you could create a different DI container for testing and inject a fake network service for testing. Using static methods makes this more awkward

Comment: @EmreO. If you are using Rx or similar, you could possibly start the request from `AppDelegate`, and listen for the response by subscribing to a stream in your `SplashVC`. But you'd have to be careful to ensure you don't miss the response if it comes back before you subscribe. I'm not too sure here - (my RxSwift is a little rusty) but other Rx libraries have 'replay' methods that allow you to access events that happened before you subscribed - this might work here.

Comment: No I'm not using Rx, just native Swift :) @RichTolley

Answer (score 2):

Usually, developers create a fake splash screen. It looks like splash, so user can't notice any difference. On controllers initializer(or in `viewDidLoad`) you can download all needed data and when everything is done go to next controller. Even more, you can choose where to go next(for example if the user was logged in before, he should be redirected to the main page).

Comment: I'm already doing like that but there is like a 3 second pass till app comes that  Splashcontroller so I'm asking If It will be better to start requests in appdelegate and wait them in splash

Comment: It will not help you as the time difference is so small, that human eye can't even catch it. If it takes a lot of time, you can show progress HUD to indicate that some processing is going. It's usual practice to do like that.